# How to use xpath for extracting text between <br/> tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Following is the code of a button in my application.

```
<span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">
New
<br>
Map
</span>
</a>
</span>
```

I want to click on that button and using Selenium Webdriver for it. I tried multiple combinations but it's not working for me. Following are the different xpaths which I tried

```
1. By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ms-cui-ctl-largelabel') and text() = 'New/nMap']"));
2. By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ms-cui-ctl-largelabel') and text() = 'New/r/nMap']")); 
3. By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ms-cui-ctl-largelabel') and text() = 'New Map']"));
```

Could someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution using [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)

```
//span[@class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" and normalize-space()="New Map"]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution looks more clear to me and I used your code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath to find span by text with `<br>` and class:

```
//span[contains(.,'New') and contains(.,'Map') and @class='ms-cui-ctl-largelabel']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. However, I have a question here, if there is another button with the property as

    <span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">
    Approve
    <br>
    Map
    </span>
    </a>
    </span>

Don't you think, the application will be confused with the above mentioned xpath as it is satisfying the criteria of 2 buttons. What should be the solution in that case ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see the updates. Could you also mark answer as accepted if it is correct?

Comment: You can also use `not(contains(.,'Approve')` to avoid multiple elements selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working for me. Marked the answer as Accepted. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone of these xpath:

1. `//span[@class='ms-cui-ctl-largelabel'][contains(., 'New')][contains(., 'Map')]`
2. `//span[contains(., 'New')][contains(., 'Map')]`
3. `//span[@class='ms-cui-ctl-largelabel']`
4. `//span[@class='ms-cui-ctl-largelabel'][contains(., 'New')]`
5. `//span[@class='ms-cui-ctl-largelabel'][contains(., 'Map')]`

> All are tested xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line:

```
//span[translate(string(),' ','')=translate('New Map',' ','')]
```

Comment: You can use codeformatting by inteding your line of code with four spaces.