# Python selenium: How to get text found between <br> tags?

Tags: python

I am beginner to python selenium and I have no idea how to get the text between these tags:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use xpath for extracting text between <br/> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268927/how-to-use-xpath-for-extracting-text-between-br-tag)

Comment: Not really, I don't get that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="required"]').text`

Can you paste this html? Or give link to the page.